# Can't unlock Pixel 6's bootloader

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock, google-pixel-6

I have no problems finding my Pixel 6 through `adb`. Also, no problems finding the device with `fastboot devices` while in fastboot**d**. But for some reason, when I switch to bootloader, the computer doesn't see the device.

Windows's USBView shows me absolutely nothing connected to the corresponding USB port. Tried on macOS as well, same thing, through 'system report' I see that literally nothing is connected to the port.

I have the latest platform tools on both PC and Mac, latest Google USB driver (on PC). USB debugging and OEM unlocking are enabled. Tried with a couple of different USB cables, in every possible port. Also, tried disabling driver signature enforcement on Windows 10 and had no luck.

I don't know what to do anymore, I read everything there is on the internet and all they say is to update drivers/change cables, etc. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "when i switch to bootloader"? Usually fastbot and bootloader mode are the same.

Comment: newer androids have a new fastbootd menu(with 'd' at the end), which is different from the bootloader, you cant flash or unlock bootloader from fastbootd menu for example

Comment: what do you mean dont need to use fastboot? is regular fastboot the bootloader?
Will try downgrading platform tools, okay, thanks

Comment: doesnt seem to work with older versions aswell... tried 30 and 31.
same thing

Comment: Maybe it's one of those devices whose boot loader can't be unlocked for [example](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/6a-from-google-cant-unlock-bootloader.4473669/)

Comment: If it's not carrier-branded , you can try [Pixel flasher](https://github.com/badabing2005/PixelFlasher) in **advanced mode** // I have not used that mode at all , so read well beforehand

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment. I didn't use `fastbootd`, normal `fastboot` was enough

Comment: I bought a compatible cable and all worked like magic.
Obviously bootloader is very pretentious

Answer (score 0):

It all worked like magic after buying a compatible USB cable.
4 days wasted for a damn cable...

A compatible USB cable in this case was a samsung one.
We tried like 6 or 7 different ones until we found the device while in bootloader with it.

Comment: While we're glad that you found a solution by yourself, could you [edit] and expand the answer? To help readers who may face the same problem, what does it mean by "compatible USB cable" in this case?